# Plugin Comentários Facebook

Tags: facebook, comentários

*Buenas* pessoal, alguém já teve problemas com o plugin de comentários do *Facebook*? Integrei ao site da firma da forma como estava descrito na plataforma, ele aparece na página porém não deixa ninguém comentar, cada vez que tento comentar ele retorna:

> "Desculpe, esse recurso não está disponível no momento"

e não salva o comentário, o estranho é que ele chega a escrever certinho o comentário, porém 1 segundo depois aparece a mensagem que citei acima.
Coloquei no Head da página o código que me passaram:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=315825798851463";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

E onde quero que apareça o comentário:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.weisetech.cf/website/pageswebsite/noticias.php" data-width="900" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Podem testar se desejarem (fico até feliz hehe) no endereço provisório que é: `weisetech.cf/noticias`

Não achei nada sobre problemas com o *plugin* no Google, recorro aos amigos do *StackOverFlow* para mais uma vez me salvar dessa.

**RESOLVIDO, pessoal não havia erro algum no código, mas como estava testando em um domínio free, acho que o facebook bloqueia de alguma forma a inserção dos comentários, ai testei no .com este MESMO código que está ai e deu certo, ufa!
Um MUITO OBRIGADO ao amigo Paulo que com os comentários a baixo me ajudou bastante a simplificar essa inserção de comentários, mais uma vez, muito obrigado a todos que tentaram de alguma forma me ajuda como o Edson e a Victoria, abraço!**

Comment: O plugin do facebook tem algumas condições para funcionar. Que você tenha sua chave ID, e que a página para comentários esteja cadastrada na ferramenta. Já verificou isso?

Comment: Não li nada sobre chave ID e nada também sobre a página ter de ser cadastrada, tem algum link de apoio sobre?

Comment: Vá até esse link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart
Repare neste parágrafo:
"....Esse código carregará e inicializará o SDK. Você deve substituir o valor em your-app-id pelo número de identificação de seu próprio Aplicativo do Facebook. Encontre esse número de identificação usando o ...."

Não é culpa sua! A documentação está mal distribuída mesmo.

Comment: Tem mais um detalhe: Eu não sei se a API ainda está aceitando HTTP

Comment: Me cadastrei lá e já consegui a ID, eles me deram esta ID: 315825798851463

Comment: A forma como coloquei apenas os números está correta Paulo?  < div id="fb-root">< /div>
 < script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = 315825798851463;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 < /script>

Comment: Tem espaço ali entre a ID e o número . Tem que tirar

Comment: Deixo: js = d.createElement(s); js.id=315825798851463; ?

Comment: Lendo melhor seu código, vi que isso não era um problema (o espaço, você está passando um inteiro), mas estou vendo outras sintaxes suspeitas. 
Chegou a colocar este código aqui?
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-numposts="5"></div>

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = 315825798851463;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 </script>


e depois onde quero que apareça os comentários:

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.weisetech.cf/website/pageswebsite/noticias.php" data-width="900" data-numposts="5"></div>

Comment: o facebook ja me deu assim o data-href, tenho de colocar este link de apoio que me passaste: developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#con‌​figurator sera?

Comment: Ainda não consigo fazer os comentários segue código como está:

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '315825798851463',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.9'
      });
      FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };
    
  (function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=315825798851463";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

Comment: Ainda não obtive êxito para conseguir comentar... HELPPPP ;/

Comment: Você tem que ir na sua área administrativa do facebook developer e desmarcar o modo de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Sim, mas isso já esta como publico amigo Paulo: segue print http://imgur.com/a/CwsDO

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59294/discussion-between-paulo-sergio-duff-and-weise).